# DIVs not aligning top left and top right using CSS float

Tags: css, html

Sorry a bit new to HTML and CSS but I have tried everything but i can't seem to get this to work. I have a top DIV and a bottom DIV. The top DIV contains two more DIVs that need to be aligned left and right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);">
            <div style="font-size: 30px; float: left;">Top Left</div>
            <div style="font-size: 30px; float: right;">Top Right</div>
        </div>
        <div >blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
            blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to see something like :

```
Top Left                          Top Right
-------------------------------------------

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

But instead i get

```
----------------------------
Top Left blah blah Top Right
```

It seems like the top DIV is getting its height set to zero. Why i have no idea. I thought if you put something in a DIV it should automatically stretch itself?

My actual code is :

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187); overflow: auto; clear: both; padding: 15px;">
    <div style="font-size: 30px;">Bearbeiten</div>
    <div style="font-size: 30px; width: 50px;">X</div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;"><input style="font-size: 15px; height: 30px; width: 130px;"
                                                      value="Cancel" class="OverlayButton" id="Overlay.CancelButton"
                                                      type="button"><input
        style="font-size: 15px; height: 30px; width: 130px;" value="Save" class="OverlayButton" type="button"><input
        style="font-size: 15px; height: 30px; width: 130px;" value="Delete" class="OverlayButton" type="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `overflow: hidden` on the div that contains the two floats.

http://jsfiddle.net/SntpD/

You could also use CSS `:after`, but it's a bit more complex.

```
.container:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SntpD/1/

Comment: thanks that did the trick on my sample code. But now that i try it in my actual code, in Firefox it seems stack the 'Left' and 'right' on top of each other. Seems to only happen in FF

Comment: @OliverWatkins you're not floating either of those divs

Comment: FF must have stripped them out. But Chrome leaves them in

Comment: Chrome : <div style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(187, 187, 187); overflow: auto; float: none; clear: both; padding: 15px;"><div style="font-size: 30px; float: left;">Bearbeiten</div><div style="font-size: 30px; float: right; width: 50px;">X</div></div>

Comment: @OliverWatkins browsers don't do that .. is there some JS running on the page?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `overflow: auto; float: none; clear: both` on the parent `div`.
`overflow: hidden` can also be used as suggested by @Explosion Pills. but this is the cleaner and more compatible way

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/yPZQ9/

Answer (score 1):

You should apply a clearing to the parent div who is containing the floats (e.g. with the given markup)

```
body > div > div:first-child {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

(of course you should use a better selector for the sake of the perfomance)

Answer (score 1):

You can give `width:50%` to both of your divs inside the top Div.

Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/v5Dn3/